# Check activity starts from which intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, intentservice

I have 3 activity. Suppose if Activity1 sends the request to an intent to start Activity 2. Similarly, if Activity 3 can also send the request to an intent to start Activity 2. So, is there any way by which in activity 2, we can get to know that from which activity request came to start this? Please someone help.

Comment: Put an extra on the `Intent` to indicate who created the `Intent`.

Comment: Please can you give an example about it. It will really be very helpful for me

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class).putExtra("origin", "Activity1"));` and `startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class).putExtra("origin", "Activity3"));` where you start the activities. `Activity2` would then call `getIntent().getExtra("origin")` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:

```
yourIntent.putExtra("FROM","A");
// or yourIntent.putExtra("FROM","B");
// or yourIntent.putExtra("FROM","C");
startActivty(yourIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 3 activities where **Activity 1** and **Activity 3** can open **Activity 2**.

From activity 1 or 3:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("origin","activity1"); // or activity3 if you're running it from activity3
startActivity(intent);
```

in **Activity 2**, you wanna detect the origin:

in `onCreate()`:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
    String origin = bundle.getString("origin");
    if(origin!=null && origin.equals("activity1")){
    //from activity1
    } 
    if(origin!=null && origin.equals("activity3")){
    //from activity3
    }
```